# Can't cast a var to expected COpaquePtr in Swift

Tags: swift

I can't cast a String (or CString) to an opaque pointer be passes as an argument to a struct expecting a COpaquePtr. I pasted to code below and I thought that any type could be casted to a void *. Not quite so. I tried a few variations (using & and casting).

```
import CoreFoundation
import CFNetwork

@objc class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        /* The server socket */
        var TCPServer: CFSocketRef

        /* The punchline to our joke */
        var punchline: CString = "To get to the other side! Ha ha!\n\r".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        /* Used by setsockopt */
        var yes: Int = 1

        /* Build our socket context; this ties the punchline to the socket */
        var CTX: CFSocketContext = CFSocketContext(version: CFIndex(0), info: punchline)
```

The error happens on the last line of this code snippet.

EDIT:

Based on Christian's answer, I wrote up the simplified version below:

```
var CTX: CFSocketContext = withUnsafePointer(&punchline) { 
    (mptr : UnsafePointer<CString>) -> (CFSocketContext) in
        return CFSocketContext(version: CFIndex(0), info: COpaquePointer(mptr))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try something like

```
var mptr : CMutablePointer<CString> = &punchline
var CTX: CFSocketContext = mptr.withUnsafePointer { (myPtr1 : UnsafePointer<CString>) -> (CFSocketContext) in
    let myOpaquePtr = COpaquePointer(myPtr1)
    return CFSocketContext(version: CFIndex(0), info: myOpaquePtr)
}
```